# How to 'listen' for future variable to resolve to TRUE without interrupting shiny application

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, future, nonblocking

In simple, I am using the future package to create a global variable in a non-blocking way in a shiny app.

The issue is finding a way for shiny to 'listen' for this global variable to exist (when future::resolved(global_var) is TRUE without interrupting the shiny application.

This is so users can create processes and eventually be informed when they are done without stopping them from continuing to use a shiny app.

I have created a simplified shiny app to illustrate this

ui.R

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application 
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),

  # Sidebar 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h4("How to listen for future event to resolve to TRUE reactively?")
    ),

    # Show status of future variable immediately
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput('future_status')
    )
  )
))
```

server.R

```
lapply(c('shiny', 'future'), require, character.only = TRUE)

# Define server logic required 
shinyServer(function(input, output) {


  global_var <<- NULL

  start.time <- Sys.time()

  global_var <<- future({
    message("Started 5 seconds til future event")
    Sys.sleep(5)
    x <- 'done'
  }) %plan% multiprocess


  message(paste0('elapsed time of ', Sys.time() - start.time, ' is less than 5'))
  message(paste0('This illustrates Non-Blocking behaviour '))


  output$future_status <- renderUI({
    val <- try({resolved(global_var)})

    h4(paste0("status is ",val))
  })


  # Reactive observe event here
  ## Initially resolved(global_var) is FALSE, 
  ### I would like to 'listen' for it to turn to TRUE without interupting the shiny app
  #### This is to act on it when it FALSE -> TRUE


  # Psuedo code
  # observeEvent({
  #   Listen for resolved(global_var) to become == TRUE, without interupting the application
  #   When and only when future(resolved(global_var)) becomes TRUE, then do some action
  # 
  # })
})
```

In line with the example

1. The global_var is set to have value of 'done' in 5 seconds after the app is started.
2. The above is done using future::future({}) combined with multiprocess; this means the app does not 'halt' and the global_var will have a value of 'done' in 5 seconds.
3. Immediately, the value of resolved(global_var) is FALSE

What I would like to do:

I want to have an observeEvent which will listen for isTRUE(resolved(global_var)); importantly, in a way where the user can continue to use the app when the event is triggered some action can be performed.

Please note that this is obviously a simplified version of the problem I am trying to solve.

Thanks

EDIT: Found a workaround using ?invalidateLater

Comment: I found a solution for this problem using also invalidateLater. Please see my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41610354/calling-a-shiny-javascript-callback-from-within-a-future/42864532#42864532. Maybe you want to share your solution as well.