# Create A Recative Timer In Shiny That Only Runs Once

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to create a reactive timer in shiny that runs only 1 time. Shiny has the reactiveTimer() function that runs every N milliseconds. I would like to create a timer that runs a conditional statement.

The function has to be reactive - other code needs to run while we are waiting for the timer to run.

I will use the timer to check a conditional statement on the Nth second.

For example,

```
observe({

    runMytimer(10)#after 10 seconds the timer runs the code below. Then it never runs again.
    if(x == 10){
    session$close()
    }

})

##The Code below still needs to run while we are waiting for the 10 seconds

observe({
print("Thanks for helping")
})

z = reactive({input$someInputId + 10})
```

Comment: Did you take a look at this thread?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41610354/calling-a-shiny-javascript-callback-from-within-a-future/42864532#42864532

Comment: I just read over it. I'm not really looking to run in parallel. It should be much simpler.  I am looking for a function like delay() from shinyjs package. However shinyjs meets to be initialized in the UI (which I dont want)